# How to create tables in word for each row in an excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, export

I'm creating a word report and all my data is on an excel sheet.
The sheet is like this:

```
ID Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
1  blah  blah  blah  blah
2  blah  blah  blah  blah
3  blah  blah  blah  blah
```

And what I want is in the word document, to have one table for each line of the worksheet like this:

```
*-------*----*
|ID     |1   |
|Name1: |blah|
|Name2: |blah|
|Name3: |blah|
|Name4: |blah|
*-------*----*

*-------*----*
|ID     |2   |
|Name1: |blah|
|Name2: |blah|
|Name3: |blah|
|Name4: |blah|
*-------*----*

etc
```

I think that this should be pretty straight forward, but unfortunatelly I've never done something like that before.

Any ideas/pointers on how ti can be done are welcome!

Comment: You've used the 'vba' and 'export' tags but have not mentioned them in your question. Are you asking for a VBA Export solution?

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm asking for any solution - thought that vba may be involved but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to reformat the data in Excel and then just copy and paste from there. For example, if you copy your table and then do a Paste Special and select the Transpose option, it will paste as:

```
ID     1     2     3     4 
Name1  blah  blah  blah  blah 
Name2  blah  blah  blah  blah
Name3  blah  blah  blah  blah
Name4  blah  blah  blah  blah
```

which will make your copy and paste a bit simpler (just select the columns you want to copy (or grab the whole table and delete the columns you don't want).

Comment: The thing is that a simple copy is not enough - I'd like each produced table to be pretty-formated, e.g. to create a template of how it should look, and the run a script to create multiple tables like that, each with data from another row.

Comment: How many tables are you doing? It may be simpler to get the data into Word and then use a Table Style to format them one by one, rather than trying to do it programmatically.

Comment: There are about 200 or something similar, not sure yet. I'll look into table style, thx for that. Can I customize it as I want?

Comment: Yep. What version of Word?

Comment: I'm using office 2010

Comment: Table Style is probably a valid approach then. Even for 200 tables.